# USB Tethering on limited data with certain provider does not count towards tethering limit of X?

Tags: usb, android, tethering

I have a contract with certain popular provider which allows say 40 gb of tethering and I have low budget phone which I frequently use for tethering. What is odd is that usb tethering does not account for the tethering metrics while hotspot does. I haven't customised anything or attempted to hide anything from the provider. Of course it is inconvenient to have phone constantly attached to PC/laptop. Given that broadband providers in some UK areas are terrible I am thinking of having second contract with provider. Yet I haven't found anything on provider pages indicating there is metrics difference. I am enjoying the bonus yet I am reluctant to verify that with the provider :-) if you see what I mean. Is it phone hiding the usage or provider choose to ignore it? I don't have second phone to verify this at the moment.

I cannot find any article or anybody else having this bonus.

Comment: It does count with my ISP/phone :/

Comment: It's provider and OS (on the phone) specific. They likely didn't realise people can tether over USB (I had this same thing happen with O2). Tethering over wifi (hotspotting) would kill my battery and require me to cable it in anyway, so I just used it as a usb modem.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am in the same situation, it is the old phone allowing this to happen. When I bought new one, both USB tethering and hotspot are reporting traffic.

Answer (score 3):

**Your USB tethering software is not reporting the tethering traffic to your carrier, nor is your carrier analyzing that traffic.**  Here's how and why it works:

Your phone and phone's OS obviously sends and receives packets to and from the internet.  This is true regardless of what your phone does with these packets.  If the traffic is generated by your phone's browser, your phone's OS knows that it is your browser.  If traffic is from another phone app, your OS know which phone app.

Typically, your android OS and phone as delivered from a provider, comes with a USB and a WiFi tethering app that is under their control.  It makes your phone look like a WiFi access point or a USB network adapter to your PC. (Windows 7 incidentally USED to also provide great WiFi tethering to other PCs OR phones, but they pulled it out of Windows 8-10).

Since your phone and/or carrier provider gave you these apps, their network is, or should be notified which traffic is tethering, and they can meter only the data that tethering app is using, either from the phone's tethering apps directly, or from the provider's back-end systems.  Typically, the carriers act as the DHCP provider for your phone's tethering apps, and handed to your connected PCs.  Since the tethering apps merely pass the traffic directly to the PCs and it or the carrier knows the PC's IPs, the tethering apps or your carrier can tell which traffic to count, and how many PCs are connected.  The metering could be done within the app itself, which reports traffic to the carrier, or the carrier can count the traffic itself.

If the app is providing your USB tethering traffic, and it is not reporting because your old phone is using an ancient version of that software (that used to report), they they can't tell you are tethering.  If they didn't write the app at all, they also can't easily tell.  They also can't *easily* tell, even when analyzing the type and destination of the traffic.  (Obviously, if it is patch Tuesday, and your PC downloads 2 GB from Microsoft, it MIGHT be tethering traffic! ;)

Since you are using a low cost, or older phone, your USB tethering software software is bypassing their metering for a number of possible reasons.